# Using a forceChatter:feed component to render activity

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, chatter, chatter-feed, app-builder

In the lightning component that I am making, I want to mimic the behaviour of the chatter feed views, `All Updates`, `Call Logs`, `Text Posts` and `Status Changes`. (In the screenshot below)

Basically I want to render them with their data in my own component.

For that I am using the component `forceChatter:feed`, and I am using it like -

```
<forceChatter:feed type="Record" />
```

I read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceChatter:feed/documentation), but I don't understand how to render feeds for different types as it comes in the screenshot. What should be the value of the `type` prop to render the feeds for `All Updates`, `Call Logs`, etc.

Any leads will help.

[image]

Comment: Hi @ghostCoder, did you find a solution for this problem ?

Comment: @altius_rup no, the design i was working on got changed. did not look into this further :(